# MySql Query Optimisation

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, I need advice on how to get data from them.

### Table name

```
details_varchar  

details_int  

details_date
```

each of them have `value_id`[Int] and `value_name` [value_name type varies as per table name - Varchar, Int, Date]

### Conditions

- only one unique `value_id` will be present in any **one** of the 3 tables. i.e ID from 1 to n are stored in these tables according to their Data Types. If value_id = 1 and value_name[type] = int then it stores in details_int table.

### What I need

`select value_name from 3 tables[may appear in any one of the table] where value_id = '[I have this value stored in a variable]'`

### What I tried

`UNION` - but all the table needs to have same column type.

`JOINS` - All the fields should be connected.[I guess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT value_name
FROM (  SELECT value_name
        FROM details_varchar
        WHERE value_id = {$int_value_id}
        UNION ALL
        SELECT value_name
        FROM details_int
        WHERE value_id = {$int_value_id}
        UNION ALL
        SELECT value_name
        FROM details_date
        WHERE value_id = {$int_value_id}) AS h
```

This should give you what you want?